# Django: Annotate with field from another table (one-to-many)

Tags: django, django-queryset, many-to-one

Good day.
I wish to annotate my model with information from a different table.

```
class CompetitionTeam(models.Model):
    competition_id = models.ForeignKey('Competition', on_delete=models.CASCADE, to_field='id', db_column='competition_id')
    team_id = models.ForeignKey('Team', on_delete=models.CASCADE, to_field='id', null=True, db_column='team_id')
    ...

class Team(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    teamleader_id = models.ForeignKey('User', on_delete=models.CASCADE, to_field='id', db_column='teamleader_id')
    ...

class Competition(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    ...
```

Looping through my competitions, I wish to retrieve the list of competitionteam objects to be displayed with the relevant team's name. I tried:

```
CompetitionTeam.objects.filter(competition_id=_competition.id).filter(team_id__in=joined_team_ids).annotate(name=...)
```

-where instead of the ellipses I put Subquery expressions in. However, I'm unsure of how to match the *team_id* variable. eg.

```
*.anotate(name=Subquery(Team.objects.filter(id=competitionteam.team_id)).values('name'))
```

Related is the question: [Django annotate field value from another model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64391494/django-annotate-field-value-from-another-model) but I am unsure of how to implement that in this case. In that case, in place of `mymodel_id`, I used `team_id` but it only had parameters from the Team object, not my competition team object. I didn't really understand `OuterRef` but here is my attempt that failed:

```
CompetitionTeam.objects.filter(competition_id=_competition.id).filter(team_id__in=joined_team_ids).annotate(name=Subquery(Team.objects.get(id=OuterRef('team_id'))))
"Error: This queryset contains a reference to an outer query and may only be used in a subquery."
```

Comment: I just tried:
`CompetitionTeam.objects.filter(competition_id=_competition.id).filter(team_id__in=joined_team_ids).annotate(name=Subquery(Team.objects.filter(id=OuterRef('team_id')).values('name')))`
 and it seems to work. I actually do not know why... I now wonder if it's possible to simplify my logic:

I wish to retrieve all competitions, the competitionteams attached to each of them and annotate their respective team names.

Comment: your code in comment works because it returns a QuerySet, `.get` doesn't allow reference to outer query (OuterRef).

Edit your question instead of commenting if you feel there's something new.

Comment: @Alvi15 Do I delete my question now? or just accept my answer. I do not want to add anything new.

Comment: I believe if you put a M2M field referring to `Competetion` model in the `Team` model then things look much easier and you can query without the inner subquery. Django automatically creates the Relation table for you in case of M2M, 121, M21, 12M. The subquery approach does not seem very efficient.

Comment: For my competition-team model, I store additional information regarding the c-t pair like join-date. I wish to ask if an M2M field is able to capture that? Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The solution for my question was:

```py
CompetitionTeam.objects.filter(
  competition_id=_competition.id,
  team_id__in=joined_team_ids
).annotate(
  name=Subquery(
    Team.objects.filter(
      id=OuterRef('team_id')
    ).values('name')
))
```

Thanks.